# In search for a good Java ODE solver

Tags: java, matlab, solver, ode

I'm working on a project to create a GUI for an algorithm in MATLAB using an ODE solver (ode45). So I have to translate the MATLAB code to Java. The problem is the ode45 solver. Java does not seem to have a solver ready to use, and ODE's are not really my speciality. Am I just not looking good, or are there really no ODE solvers for Java implemented?

thanks

Comment: And with an ODE solver I mean a solver comparable to ode45 :)

Comment: Okay for anyone else interested: http://simcity.usask.ca/wp-content/uploads/2010/02/mpatterson_bcs_thesis.pdf

Answer (score 5):

If you need a mathematical library for Java, there are several available on the market, either open-source or commercial. These are few ones.

- JMSL by Roguewave, entirely written in Java , which we use succesfully at work
- NAG, written in C but widely documented so that can be used from Java
- Apache commons math, which is open source and contains also a ODE http://commons.apache.org/math/userguide/ode.html

Answer (score 1):

not exactly what you asked but did you consider creating the GUI from matlab instead? it's not that different from basic java swing/awt things unless you're looking for fancy GUI things.

http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/creating_guis/bqz6qcd.html

Comment: Well, actually I did consider that. But the GUI is for a larger project, and one requirement is that the user doesn't have to install external software to run it. So that leaves me with either Java (negating the JRE installation) or C/C++.

Comment: might want to consider matlab compiler, which allows you to package matlab application into components for use in c/c++, java, etc or distributables that can run without matlab installed. http://www.mathworks.com/products/compiler/description3.html

Comment: Matlab compiler is too expensive